# How to add the condition on inter table not relation table when defining a model relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-7, laravel-5.7

I have a relation table named `company_team` it relation to `company` and `user`, and there is a field `is_ceo` in `company_team` table to flag weather a company team member is an ceo. following is my model define

```
class CompanyTeam extends Pivot
{
    /**
     * return all company team member with out ceo
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function team_member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * return only ceo's info
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function company_ceo()
    {
        $this->where('is_ceo', 1); // it dosen't work, but it is effect l want
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

l searched an answer with using `addGlobalScope`, but it doesn't fit me, because when l use both of `team_member` and `company_ceo` relation, it will add condition on both of then

Comment: I have tried yet, doesn't work

Comment: What about local scope?

Answer (score 1):

In user model, you can define a scope

```
public function scopeCompanyCeo($query){
return $query->where('is_ceo',1);
}
```

then you can use like in your controller

```
$user = User::find(1)->companyCeo()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add conditions when defining the relationship.
You have to add the condition when performing the queries.

`CompanyTeam::with(['company_ceo' => function ($q) use() {
     $q->where('is_ceo', 1);
 }])
 ->get();`

Comment: it doesn't work, because `is_ceo` was defined on `compnay_team` table, your way will add condition like `where user.is_ceo = 1` and throw an db error `column user.is_ceo does't exist`

Comment: change to $q->where('company_team.is_ceo', 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function company_ceo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id')->where('is_ceo', 1);
}
```

I hope this helps. Have a great day and happy coding... :)